# Query to calculate the revenue of a performance in total revenue of all the performances

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, error-handling, sql-server-2012

I am looking to fine the number of tickets booked for a performance + total revenue of that performance compared to the total revenue of all the performances. I have managed to count the number of tickets booked but its the full query doesnt work and giving me error.

sample result will be following for example:

```
`tickets booked = 9
 total revenue of the performance = xxx$
 total revenue of all the performances = xxx$
```

the query i am using is this:

```
 SET @performancerevenue = '50 Shades of Grey';
 select distinct P.perName as Performance, 
 (select COUNT(ticketBooked) from bookings as B 
 inner join performances as P on 
 B.perID = p.perID where perName = @performancerevenue) as
 [Number of Ticket Booked ], 
 CAST(AVG((T.ticketPrice*left(B.totalCost,1))) over() as decimal(6,2))    as[Total Revenue from the performance (£)], 
 CAST(AVG(convert(decimal(5,2),(left(PY.totalAmount,1)))) over() as   decimal(5,2)) as [Total revenue]
 from performances as P
 inner join tickets as T
 on T.perID = P.perID
 inner join bookings as B
 on T.bookingID = B.bookingID
 inner join payments as PY
 where P.perName = @performancerevenue
```

The table and Sample Data is as follows :

```
 CREATE TABLE bookings( 
 bookingID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,  
 customerID int ,
 clerkID varchar (20) ,
 perID int,
 ticketBooked int, 
 bookingDate Date,   
 bookingTime time,
 bookingType varchar(20),
 totalCost decimal(5,2),
 PRIMARY KEY (bookingID),
 FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customers,
 FOREIGN Key (clerkID) REFERENCES clerks,);

 insert into bookings values (16, 'clerk04', 1, 2, '2015-02-24', '12:00',  'Normal', '20');
 insert into bookings values (2, 'clerk02', 20,3, '2015-02-25', '15:00', 'Advance', '34');
 insert into bookings values (10, 'clerk04', 3,5, '2015-02-17', '18:00', 'Advance', '75');
 insert into bookings values (5, 'clerk01', 19,2, '2015-01-24', '21:00', 'Advance', '30');
 insert into bookings values (13, 'clerk01', 4,1, '2015-02-05', '12:00', 'Normal', '10');
 insert into bookings values (20, 'clerk04', 5,1,'2015-01-26', '15:00', 'Normal', '12');
 insert into bookings values (4, 'clerk03', 6, 3,'2015-02-09', '18:00', 'Advance', '30');
 insert into bookings values (1, 'clerk03', 2, 1,'2015-01-03', '21:00', 'Advance', '15');
 insert into bookings values (17, 'clerk04', 3, 1,'2015-02-09', '12:00', 'Normal', '12');


 CREATE TABLE performances( 
 perID int IDENTITY (1,1)NOT NULL,  
 perName varchar (50),
 perTime Time,
 perDate Date, 
 perType varchar (20),
 duration varchar (10),
 screenNo int,
 rating varchar (10),
 location varchar (10),
 PRIMARY KEY (perID),);
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '12:00', '2015-03-08', 'Movie', '2hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '15:00', '2015-02-20', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '18:00', '2015-02-26', 'Movie', '2hrs', '3', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '21:00', '2015-03-28', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Paddington', '12:00', '2015-03-26', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Paddington', '15:00', '2015-03-03', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Paddington', '18:00', '2015-02-02', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Paddington', '21:00', '2015-03-31', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '1', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '12:00', '2015-02-25', 'Movie', '3hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '15:00', '2015-02-06', 'Movie', '3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '18:00', '2015-02-13', 'Movie', '3hrs', '3', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '21:00', '2015-01-09', 'Movie', '3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '12:00', '2015-01-11', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '1', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '15:00', '2015-01-19', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '18:00', '2015-02-06', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '21:00', '2015-01-02', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '2', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '12:00', '2015-01-06', 'Movie', '2hrs', '1', '18', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '15:00', '2015-03-28', 'Movie', '2hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '18:00', '2015-02-09', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
 insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '21:00', '2015-02-06', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');

 CREATE TABLE payments( 
 paymentID int IDENTITY (1,1) not null,
 bookingID int, 
 totalAmount decimal (5,2),
 paymentType varchar (20), 
 paymentDate Date, 
 PRIMARY KEY (paymentID),
 FOREIGN KEY (bookingID) REFERENCES bookings,);
 insert into payments values (1, 20, 'Cash', '2015-01-20');
 insert into payments values (10, 20, 'Cash', '2015-01-17');
 insert into payments values (12, 12, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-03-31');
 insert into payments values (5, 10, 'Cash', '2015-01-08');
 insert into payments values (18, 12, 'Cash', '2015-03-22');
 insert into payments values (3, 75, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-02-21');
 insert into payments values (2, 34, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-03-26');
 insert into payments values (9, 12, 'Cash', '2015-03-26');
 insert into payments values (13, 20, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-01-23');
 insert into payments values (16, 20, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-03-08');
 insert into payments values (11, 45, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-02-21');
 insert into payments values (4, 30, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-02-08');
 insert into payments values (7, 30, 'Cash', '2015-01-20');
 insert into payments values (20, 30, 'Cash', '2015-02-26');
 insert into payments values (14, 20, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-03-17');
 insert into payments values (19, 45, 'Cash', '2015-01-10');
 insert into payments values (6, 12, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-02-02');
 insert into payments values (20, 30, 'Cash', '2015-02-01');
 insert into payments values (17, 34, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-03-27');
 insert into payments values (15, 15, 'Credit/Debit Card', '2015-02-14');
```

i have been trying so hard to get the result working for the last 4 hours but it just giving me errors I will really appreciate your help :(

thanks

Comment: "followed by the total revenue of that particular performance in total revenue of all the performances."  I don't follow what you are trying to produce.  Can you edit the question and provide sample results to go with the sample data?

Comment: Hi Gordon Sorry for the confusion I have edited the question please have a look, Thanks

Comment: Hi,  Could you post the error please.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'COUNT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you can get the desired result by following way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 P.perName as [Perf], 
 SUM(B.ticketBooked) OVER(PARTITION BY P.perName) as [BookedTickets],
 SUM(B.totalCost) OVER(PARTITION BY P.perName) as [PerfRevenue],
 SUM(B.totalCost) OVER() as [TotalRevenue]
 from bookings as B 
 inner join performances as P on B.perID = p.perID
```

This query results something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Perf                BookedTickets   PerfRevenue TotalRevenue
------------------+---------------+------------+------------
50 Shades of Grey   15              196.00      238.00
Paddington           4              42.00       238.00
```

And you can add any outer query for this table for additional filtering and calculations.